# How to properly assign style.backgroundClip = "text"?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am having trouble with one line of code. I have been searching the web for hours now and had to resort to stack overflow. When I run this code, it does nothing. Here is the code:

```
e.style.backgroundClip = "text";
```

When I researched this, I found that the "text" is not officially existing, however if I use this in the css with background-clip it works. If you have any idea why this is not working, please help. I am using a device running iOS 8 if that helps.

**I AM USING A PROGRAM CALLED "EXPRESSO HTML"**

Comment: it's a browser isssue

Comment: `background-clip: "text"` is a webkit attribute. http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

Comment: Can't you use a CSS class and toggle it with javascript instead ?

Comment: I'm trying to use purely javascript for this

Answer (score 0):

Setting `text` as the value for `background-clip` property is not a recognised value in the specification:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Values

You could force the element to take the inline styling like so:

```
el.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-background-clip:text");
```

Notice it also takes the `-webkit-` vendor prefix. I think only Chrome supports it, I may be wrong.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crwk2mac/

Since this variation of `background-clip` is not well supported, it would not be advisable to use it without decent and well tested fallbacks. This would be best done in CSS and could give you a real headache trying to implement entirely in javascript.

Comment: Chrome doesn't use webkit anymore. Only Safari (and safari on iOS) use webkit.

Comment: For the programming software I am using, it doesn't matter if I use -WebKit or not.

Comment: @dany123awesome I can't see what doesn't work about it. Here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/crwk2mac/

Comment: @slebetman `background-clip:text` does not work on Chrome without the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: If anybody needs to know, I am using a program called "Expresso HTML"

Comment: @dany123awesome Like I say, as far as I'm aware background-clip:text is only supported by webkit and Chrome, so if you are using anything else, it will not work. Nonetheless, my answer will apply the correct inline style code, which will work in webkit browsers.